# how to understand this identity about the range in linear algebra

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I see the identity in page 48 of paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.4061.pdf. Specially,
if  $U^TU=UU^T=I$, then we will have $U^T\text{range}(M)=\text{range}(U^TM)$, where $\text{range}(M)$ means the column space of a certain matrix $M$.

My question is: if $\text{range}(M)$ means the row space of $M$, then I can understand the identity $U^T\text{range}(M)=\text{range}(U^TM)$. However, here $\text{range}(M)$ means the column space of a certain matrix $M$, making me confused on the identity $U^T\text{range}(M)=\text{range}(U^TM)$. Could anybody give some help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does $U^T\text{range}(M) = \text{range}(U^TM)$ mean "if $x \in \text{range}(M)$, then $U^Tx \in \text{range}(U^TM)$"?

Comment: @echo yes, and vice verse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to prove that

> $x \in \text{range}(M)$ is equivalent to $U^Tx \in \text{range}(U^TM)$, given that $UU^T = U^TU = I$

- First, we prove $x \in \text{range}(M) \implies U^Tx \in \text{range}(U^TM)$

Since $x\in \text{range}(M)$, there exists $y$ such that $x = My$. Thus
$$
U^Tx = U^TMy = (U^TM)y
$$
implying $U^Tx$ is a linear combination of columns of $U^TM$, thus
$$
U^Tx \in \text{range}(U^TM)
$$

- Next, we prove that $U^Tx \in \text{range}(U^TM) \implies x \in \text{range}(M)$

Since $U^Tx \in \text{range}(U^TM)$, we have $U^Tx = U^TMy$ for some $y$. Thus
$$
U^T(x - My) = 0
$$
Since $U^T$ is non-singular, $x - My$ must be $0$, implying $x = My$, i.e.,
$$
x \in \text{range}(M)
$$

---

**Note**: To see $U^T$ is non-singular, use $UU^T = U^TU = I$.